# VS Code terminal in Mac OS Siera - how to stop process?

Tags: macos, terminal, visual-studio-code

I've changed Windows on MacOS and met the problem with stopping processes in terminal. In standart Terminal CMD+. works, but not in VS Code.
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> doesn't works.
It's really unconvenient to close terminal completelly to stop processes. It was very easy in windows, but why here's a problems...

Answer (score 7):

just hit control <kbd>^</kbd> + C. make sure you hit Control not Command (<kbd>⌘</kbd>), that cot me many times :)

Answer (score 0):

Under the view menu, there is an option to display integrated Terminal. This opens a Unix shell window at bottom of VScode window. You should be able to kill whatever process is causing you problems.